# CSS for disabled asp button

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a ASP button which is disabled (enabled=false) by default. I cannot set the CSS style for this button as long as it is disabled. As soon as it is enabled, the style is alright. I have tried using the :disabled CSS attribute but no luck. What am I missing?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnImport" Enabled="false" runat="server" class="button" Text="Import" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
```

And the CSS:

```
.button:disabled
{
    background-color: #9dc9ed;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 36px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #9dc9ed;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 36px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: What can u see when inspecting button on browser ?

Comment: it seems like you have no problem in your markup. Try in another browser or check whether the browser supports css3

Comment: But both styles are the same, how would you tell the difference between states?